# how to get android system default home app's name

Tags: android

If my phone is installed 3-4 home(launcher) apps,when I press home key,it will show a dialog to display the home apps that installed on my phone,then I will choose one as default.My question is:
Can I get the default home app's package name through codes?

Solve it,use the follow api.

```
public abstract int getPreferredActivities (List<IntentFilter> outFilters, List<ComponentName> outActivities, String packageName)
```

Comment: Home apps or widgets on home screen?

Comment: It's the default launcher(home app),for example,facebook home is my default home,how can I get its package name through codes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you have a look at:  [PackageManager.resolveActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29),

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo defaultLauncher= getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String nameOfLauncherPkg= defaultLauncher.activityInfo.packageName;
```

Make sure you use HOME intent as you will have the launcher on home, obviously.

Haven't used but you can try it with another flag i.e.

`PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS` in place of

```
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
```

> **FINAL SOLUTION:**

**API packageManager,**

```
public abstract int getPreferredActivities (List<IntentFilter> outFilters,List<ComponentName> outActivities, String packageName)
```

Comment: But I want to know the default used home,if I install more than one home apps on my phone

Comment: I find the api in packageManager,it can solve my problem,public abstract int getPreferredActivities (List<IntentFilter> outFilters, List<ComponentName> outActivities, String packageName)

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that return a String Array contains all the home apps on the device:

```
public String[] getDefaultLauncherList() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = ((PackageManager)getPackageManager()).queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);      
    String[] toReturn=new String[list.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        toReturn[i]=list.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
    return toReturn;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a method I use:

```
private String nameOfHomeApp()
    {
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            return mInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```